# C# Round up and down

Tags: c#

I'm counting the results of my database.
If it's lower then 50, i want to divide them by 2.
Example:

```
if(CountResults < 50)
{
    //CountResults = 39
    int divided = CountResults / 2; //Results in 19
}
```

What i want:

```
if(CountResults < 50)
{
    //CountResults = 39
    int divided = CountResults / 2; //Results in 19,5
    Math.Round(divided, 0);
}
```

I want to be able to round it upwards and down.

So i get the result **19.5** twice. Once i want it to be **19**, and once to be **20.**.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Divide it by `2.0` in stead of `2`.

Comment: First of all, by default C# uses integer math - when you divide integer by integer, you get integer. And second - you have shown only first piece of code. How do you get second result? It's not clear how do you get two results in `divided` variable

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy to get the CountResults, i loop the query results, and count them via Int CountResults. This way i know how many results i have. Then i want to divide that by 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear how you are going to use your code twice, but if you want to divide integer into two integer parts just subtract first result from totals:

```
if(CountResults < 50)
{
    //CountResults = 39
    int divided1 = CountResults / 2;        // 19
    int divided2 = CountResults - divided1; // 20
}
```

First result will use integer division and it will give you result rounded towards zero (19 in your case). Further reading: [C# Specification 7.7.2 Division Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Second result will give you rest which will be either equal to first result (if there was no rounding), or it will be equal to division rounded from zero (20 in your case).

Comment: This did it for me. Was prety simple however i did not think of it :/ 
Thank you!

Comment: @Mitch just remember about integer division in C# (I have added link for you)

Answer (score 4):

The rounding part can be accomplished using these 2 nice methods:

[Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx) brings it to the floor

[Math.Celing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx) lifts it to the celing ;)

The calculation part is a little more tricky. This statement:

```
int divided = CountResults / 2; //Results in 19,5
```

cannot really be true, or let's say it does not matter what is behind the comma because when it is assigned to the variable `int devided` it will loose this information and no rounding is anymore required.
When you want a result of type `double` (meaning e.g. `19,5` ) and you want to round that result, you need at least one of the parameters of the calculation to be of type double `double`!

Example

```
double var1 = 39;

int res_low = (int)Math.Floor(var1 / 2);
int res_high = (int)Math.Ceiling(var1 / 2);
```

note that writing `2` is implicitly seen by the compiler as `int` and writing `2.0` is implicitly seen as `double`. So this would yield the same result:

```
int var2 = 39;

int res_low2 = (int)Math.Floor(var2 / 2.0);
int res_high2 = (int)Math.Ceiling(var2 / 2.0);
```

Comment: Thank you, this also is working. If i could accept multiple answers i would.